# how to do this scrolling effect?

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

its been a day and am still not able to get the idea how this is being done:

https://in.bookmyshow.com/careers/

the part of 'A day at the book office'.

How does that scrolling effect happen?

I thought to do this:

1. keep count of the scroll position.
2. show content based on the scroll position.
3. don't scroll the body but keep changing the scroll value.

I mean, for some time I keep scrolling and nothing happens, and then suddenly the contents change.

So during this process how is the body content kept fixed?

or is it something different altogether?

please help.

Comment: You can take  a look at some of the js scrolling libraries. Or some mixed libraries, for example: http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".